# Portable selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, portability

For all my projects written in python where I use selenium to scrape websites I can only run the script from my own machine and if I were to send the script to a client if say he needed it to run on a daily basis, it most probably wouldn't work.

Is there a way to use selenium webdriver in a way for the script to be portable and able to run from any platform so that I could send it to my clients and be confident that it would work. I couldn't find anything definite on the internet that would help me.

If this is not possible with selenium is it possible with some other python module? So far for pages that use javascript I used selenium for scraping. Should I switch to something else for portability? Please advise me. I would really appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction.

Comment: What problems are you having with your code running on other machines? If you bundle your app with the driver, as long as the client has a compatible version of firefox/chrome, for example, you should be fine. Another option would be to bundle phantomJS, but that project has been discontinued and is no longer supported by selenium.

Answer (score 0):

I would download a version of your browser driver (e.g. [chromedriver for Chrome](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.37/)) for *all available platforms* and put all of them in the script folder.
I would then zip it and share it with the customer.

It would also be quite easy to build a script that automatically checks local Operating System and dowloads the needed driver from internet (using Python wget or similar) but I do not see a serious advantage in using this approach.

As a final thought it is also possible using [Selenium with remote WebDriver](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html#selenium-remote-webdriver) but that would complicate things and leave you with a server to mantain and update.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I was hoping that there is a better way without needing to worry about compatibility issues with browser and selenium